# Javascript “onclick” event does not load on submit button

Tags: javascript

Here's my code:

```
www.<input class="text" type="text" value="" name="domain" id="domain" />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" 
           onclick="mostrar_cpanel(document.forms[0].domain.value,'rpta_domain')" />
<br /><br />
```

The onclick JavaScript function will not run. Can someone please help?

Comment: Provide more code, such that is related to your question.

Comment: Basically, I am attempting to create a button similar to what is seen here: https://www.webhostinglogic.com/webmail/webmail-clients.html - i need users to enter their address or domain.

Comment: Yes, however, you call this function `mostrar_cpanel` without providing us the code to that function. A fiddle would be helpful.

Comment: My apologies: function mostrar_cpanel(valor,idrecibir)
{
 //alert('alerta');
 axc('../ajax/cpanel.php?domain='+valor,idrecibir,'submit');
 }
function mostrar_webmail(valor,idrecibir)
{
 //alert('alerta');
 axc('../ajax/webmail.php?domain='+valor,idrecibir,'submit');
 }

Comment: Don't give a form control a name of "submit", it will mask the form's submit method so you can't call it.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip

Comment: more you script code please

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `<form>` than your submit action element will try to trigger a browser default *follow* - resulting in a page refresh.
If instead you have other plans for your form you can [Event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) the action that would otherwise occur, allowing you to move forward with any javascript execution you planned.

Additionally, to output the desired values to an element use `document.getElementById` and than `innerHTML` like:

```js
function mostrar_cpanel(val, str) {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("myOutput").innerHTML= val+' '+str;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input class="text" type="text" value="" name="domain" id="domain" />
  <input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="mostrar_cpanel(document.forms[0].domain.value,'rpta_domain')" />
  <div id="myOutput"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is there anyway to make this run similiar to what's seen here: https://www.webhostinglogic.com/webmail/webmail-clients.html, basically without the alerts.

Comment: @Nick yes. By not using the alert :) but outputting the `val` and `str` to a HTML element.

Comment: Hahah I'm very new to this...any pointers on how to accomplish this? I'd like to learn

Comment: @Nick by using Google is a good start: "JS how to get an element" and "JS how to add HTML to an element". So basically: `document.getElementById("myElementId").innerHTML= val+' '+str;`

Comment: @RobG yes, I know that very well, believe me, I'm on it :) thx btw